# Can a nondeterministic finite automata (NDFA) be efficiently converted to a deterministic finite automata (DFA) in subexponential space/time?

Tags: dfa, regular-expressions, bounds

Twenty years ago, I built an regular expression package that included conversions from regular expressions to a finite state machine (DFA) and supported a host of closed regular expression  operations (Kleene star, concatenation, reverse, set operations, etc). I was unsure about the worst case performance of my package.

A DFA has the same expressive power as an NDFA, because an n-state NDFA can be trivially converted to a DFA having 2^n states. However, are there any lower upper bound guarantees for such a conversion that do not require an exponential explosion in state?

I was unable to come up with examples mal-behaving regular expressions or NDFAs, but I didn't spend much time thinking about it. I am guessing a regular expression like ((((e|A|B|C)*(e|D|E|F))*(e|G|H|I))*(e|J|K|L|M))* which mixes a lot of alternations and Kleene stars would have a linearly sized NDFA but an expansive DFA.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the class of NFAs that you would want to accept as input?  Some restrictions lead to better upper bounds.

Comment: not a very important point, but need ndfa be its own tag?

Comment: Yes there are restrictions. The NFAs are constructed directly from regular expressions by treating them as generalized transition graphs. http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cit596/notes/dave/regexp-nfa4.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is known that for every pair of naturals numbers `n,a` such that `n <= a <= 2^n`, there exists a minimal NDFA with `n` states whose corresponding equivalent minimal dfa has `a` states (over a four letter alphabet).

See the paper here: [Deterministic blow-ups of minimal nondeterministic finite automata over a fixed alphabet](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1770337&dl=GUIDE&coll=GUIDE&CFID=100818292&CFTOKEN=24447810).

Abstract of the paper:

> We show that for all integers n and α
>   such that n ≤ α ≤ 2^n, there exists a
>   minimal nondeterministic finite
>   automaton of n states with a
>   four-letter input alphabet whose
>   equivalent minimal deterministic
>   finite automaton has exactly a states.
>   It follows that in the case of a
>   four-letter alphabet, there are no
>   "magic numbers", i.e., the holes in
>   the hierarchy. This improves a similar
>   result obtained by Geffert for a
>   growing alphabet of size n + 2 (Proc.
>   7th DCFS, Como, Italy, 23-37).

So, I suppose the answer to your question is, no.

Comment: the question is asking for an "algorithm" running in subexponential time and space for converting the NFA.

Comment: @Marcos: If your output is exponential, you cannot possibly have an algorithm that runs in sub-exponential time.

Comment: This is a general result.  If there are known restrictions on the class of input NFAs, then it might be possible to do better.

Comment: @Andras: Agreed, but given that this is probably programming related (which will support Kleen * etc), I doubt if the set of input NFA will be restricted to a proper subset.

Comment: This result was recently strengthened to use a three letter alphabet, and the constructions are a bit simpler: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1575787.1575813&coll=Portal&dl=GUIDE&CFID=98498868&CFTOKEN=60579493

Answer (score 14):

The classic example for a language with an exponential separation between DFA size and NFA size is the following finite language: binary strings of length exactly 2n in which the first half is not equal to the second half.  A NFA would guess an index i in which the first and second half disagree.  A lower bound for a DFA follows from communication complexity, for example.

Comment: Another maybe simpler example is "the n-th character before the end of the word is an $a$". Can be done with $n+1$ states with an NFA that guesses when the end of the word occurs, whereas a DFA clearly needs to have $2^n$ states as each of the possible states of the $n$ last characters define a different set of continuations that make the automaton accept.

Answer (score 8):

The minimum DFA corresponding to an NFA has 2^n states in the worst case, so you can't garantee anything. Without having a constructive example, the reasoning is that in an NFA you can be at any arbitrary subset of states after reading a certain input string, and each such subset might behave differently when observing one character. Suppose a language with two characters in the alphabet (a and b), and an NFA N with n states that starts with an accepting state at s_0. Now enumerate all subsets of states of N, and build the transition table such that observing "a" from subset S_i takes you to subset S_i+1 and observing b takes you to subset S_i-1 (this is doable for some enumerations, I think). Now this automata has n states and accepts sequences of m a's and n  b's such that m-n = 0 mod 2^|N|, and cannot be expressed with a DFA that has less than 2^|N| states (since it might need to cycle through all subsets of states of the NFA N).

Comment: Can this be turned into an argument that says "if (some bad thing) is avoided in the NFA, then the DFA has subexponential number of states"?

Comment: @András, yes.  "If nondeterminism is avoided in the NFA, then the DFA has subexponential number of states".

Comment: Pavel, yes, obviously.  Is there any non-trivial property that can be recognized efficiently which also guarantees subexponential blowup?